# VBA match rows between two sheets with different row indexes

Tags: excel, vba, match

i have a code that match the rows in two sheets and paste the matched rows in sheet3 and the unmatched rows in sheet4. The correct output occur when the first row in sheet1 is matched with the first row in sheet2. The problem is that the row(s) with difference doesnt get shown in sheet4

Can anyone help me, where have i made a mistake? I want to have a code that just match the rows no matter which row index they have. It can varie for each input.

My code is:

```
Sub MatchRows()

    Dim a As Variant, b As Variant, c As Variant, d As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, m As Long, n As Long
    Dim dic As Object, ky As String

    Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    a = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:I" & Sheets("Sheet1").Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(3).Row).Value
    b = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:I" & Sheets("Sheet2").Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(3).Row).Value
    ReDim c(1 To UBound(a, 1), 1 To UBound(a, 2))
    ReDim d(1 To UBound(a, 1), 1 To UBound(a, 2))

    For i = 1 To UBound(b, 1)
        ky = b(i, 3) & "|" & b(i, 4) & "|" & b(i, 5) & "|" & b(i, 9)
        dic(ky) = i
    Next

    For i = 1 To UBound(a, 1)
        ky = a(i, 3) & "|" & a(i, 4) & "|" & a(i, 5) & "|" & a(i, 9)
        If dic.exists(ky) Then
            j = dic(ky)
            If a(i, 8) = b(j, 8) Then
                k = k + 1
                For n = 1 To UBound(a, 2)
                    c(k, n) = a(i, n)
                Next
                c(k, 8) = 0
            Else
                m = m + 1
                For n = 1 To UBound(a, 2)
                    d(m, n) = a(i, n)
                Next
                d(m, 8) = a(i, 8) - b(j, 8)
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox "'" & ky & "' not matched on row " & i + 1   
        End If
    Next

    If k > 0 Then Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(3)(2).Resize(k, UBound(a, 2)).Value = c
    If m > 0 Then Sheets("Sheet4").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(3)(2).Resize(m, UBound(a, 2)).Value = d

End Sub
```

The lines match although they are on different row indexes in sheet1 and sheet2, which is good. The problem is now that the row where there is a difference, doesn't get shown in sheet4 (difference sheet)

Comment: In the second loop ky should be built from `a` not `b`. `ky = a(i, 1) & "|" & a(i, 2)  etc`

Comment: Ah perfect, thanks! will try that, hope it works

Comment: @CDP1802 Okay now i compute the correct rows that match although they are on different lines. But now there is no rows pasted into the sheet where the differences should be stated? Its just empty

Comment: See updated code. It doesnt copy any of the rows with difference into the sheet4 (difference sheet). Why is that?

Comment: why have you changed the key column from 3,4,5,9 which is C,D,E,I on previous question to 1,2,4,6,7 now ?

Comment: My bad, but that isnt the problem. The code does the same if i write 3, 4, 5, 9 or 1, 2, 4, 6, 7

Comment: What do you mean by "does the same" ? Do any of the records appear on sheet 3 ? If so are they the matching ones or all of them ?

Comment: @CDP1802 see updated question in the top. changed the text and added som new pics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a message box to identify non-matched keys

```vb
    For i = 1 To UBound(a, 1)
        ky = a(i, 3) & "|" & a(i, 4) & "|" & a(i, 5) & "|" & a(i, 9)
        If dic.exists(ky) Then
            j = dic(ky)
            If a(i, 8) = b(j, 8) Then
                k = k + 1
                For n = 1 To UBound(a, 2)
                    c(k, n) = a(i, n)
                Next
                c(k, 8) = 0
            Else
                m = m + 1
                For n = 1 To UBound(a, 2)
                    d(m, n) = a(i, n)
                Next
                d(m, 8) = a(i, 8) - b(j, 8)
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox "'" & ky & "' not matched on row " & i + 1
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: Is this just to check which keys that doesn't match?

Comment: @anon yes did the missing record 2222 show ?

Comment: yes see the updated question. It shows in the message box

Comment: @anon Autofit the columns on sheet1 and inspect row 3

Comment: What do you mean by inspect row 3?

Comment: @Anon I mean check the values in the key columns C,D,E and I especially column E and I, there is something wrong in the data , 90000 should not be in the key

Comment: How can I check the values? Like try to delete all rows and fill it out again or can I do something in the VBA code?

Comment: @anon Check the lines `ky = a(i, 3) & "|" & a(i, 4) & "|" & a(i, 5) & "|" & a(i, 9)` and `ky = b(i, 3) & "|" & b(i, 4) & "|" & b(i, 5) & "|" & b(i, 9)` I dont see how you can get 90000 from column H (8) into the key ?

Comment: okay will check the lines

Comment: I have made debug.print ky both lines where i have a ky value. The ky value contains the correct lines in the right order, so that should be fine. I made a debug.print a(i, 8), and debug.print b(j, 8). This now shows to times 100000 which is okay, and two times 50000 which is okay. But im missing the row with the value 90000 and 110000? Why isnt those two values there???

Comment: @anon the keys are not fine .they should only have 3 vertical lines separating the 4 columns  3,4,5 and 9. The values from  column H should NOT be in the key.

Comment: It works! Thank you so much for the help! Appreciate it very much. Is it possible that you update your answer by deleting the column with the amount? Then i will give the check mark